# Does the observer effect apply to light sources?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

A popular thought experiment for explaining how observation affects that which is observed, is to point out that observing an object requires bouncing photons off it, which will affect the object's momentum.

However, what if we are observing photons that are *emitted* by the object at regular intervals? Whether such photons intersect with a sensor or not does not appear to affect the momentum of the emitter.

How do we reconcile the results of these two thought experiments?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are observing photons that are emitted from an object, when you detect them, they will still interact with whatever device you are using to do this. So while the momentum of the photons leaving the emitter might not be disturbed, their momentum will be changed when they enter the detector and interact with its constituents.

Comment: Yes, but won't this allow us to measure the emitter precisely without ever having disturbed the emitter itself (since we're intercepting an emitted photon and not bouncing it off the emitter)? As I wrote that, I'm kind of starting to sense the answer (probably has to do with the effect of the emission on the emitter), but would like to hear how you would put it in proper terms.